# Why design ThreadLocalMap as static nest class in ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, static

Why design `ThreadLocalMap` as Static Class in `ThreadLocal`? While static and non-static nested classes have differences below.

1. Nested static class doesn’t need reference of Outer class, but Non-static nested class or Inner class requires Outer class reference.
2. Inner class(or non-static nested class) can access both static and non-static members of Outer class. A static class cannot access non-static members of the Outer class. It can access only static members of Outer class.
3. An instance of Inner class cannot be created without an instance of outer class and an Inner class can reference data and methods defined in Outer class in which it nests, so we don’t need to pass reference of an object to the constructor of the Inner class. For this reason Inner classes can make program simple and concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it should be noted that `ThreadLocalMap` is a package-private class, thus it's not a part of the API, but an implementation detail which may change in future JDK versions if necessary.

Why it's not non-static? Just because non-static nested class (inner class) is bound to the concrete instance of the outer class. In our case it should be bound to the concrete `ThreadLocal` variable. This is just wrong: `ThreadLocalMap` is bounded to the thread and stores all the values of all `ThreadLocal` variables for given thread. Thus binding it to the concrete `ThreadLocal` instance is meaningless.

Maybe it looks more logical to make `ThreadLocalMap` the inner class of the `Thread` class. However `ThreadLocalMap` just does not need the `Thread` object to operate, so this would just add some unnecessary overhead. The reason it's located inside the `ThreadLocal` class is that the `ThreadLocal` is responsible for `ThreadLocalMap` creation. `ThreadLocalMap` is created for current thread only when the first `ThreadLocal` is set in this thread, but after that the same `ThreadLocalMap` is used for all other `ThreadLocal` variables.

Another alternative would be to hold `ThreadLocalMap` as separate package-private class in `java.lang` package. Nothing wrong with such option: it's just a matter of taste and depends on what developers want more: to group related functionality in single source file or to keep source file length smaller.